# Updating model value in Angular Bootstrap UI typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the [Angular Bootstrap UI typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and **trying to update the model value inside the typeahead**. But the updated model value does not reflect the changes unless specifically applied.

```
<input ng-model="query" typeahead="option for option in getOptions($viewValue)">

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.query = '';
  $scope.getOptions = function(query){
    if(query == "foo"){
      $scope.query = "foobar";
      // uncommenting the next line works but also raises error
      // $scope.$apply()
      return []
    }
    return ["I have an idea", "I have new idea"];
  }
});
```

**Plunker Code:** http://plnkr.co/edit/pNxBMgeKYulLuk7DO0gB?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by watching the value of `$scope.query`.

In the `$watch`, `newValue` and `oldValue` represent the value of `$scope.query` after and before it is changed, respectively.

```
$scope.$watch("query", function(newValue, oldValue){
  if (newValue !== oldValue) {
    if (newValue === "foo") {
      $scope.query = "foobar";
    }
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Fsj8KWuSzr9VTMkKB9wO?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, that works perfectly. I am still unable to understand why updating model inside getOptions() doesn't work, while $watch works?

Comment: One thing I can note is that there is no `$scope.apply()` method. However there is a `$scope.$apply()` which also cause an error of $apply already in progress.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the `$`. I was trying to avoid the $apply() thing.

Comment: I believe that it is changing the `$scope.query` to foobar successfully. However the typeahead is coming along and stomping all over that scope variable after is its changed in `getOptions()` Have a look here http://plnkr.co/edit/i2l0z5EIiUUujVhAlJig?p=preview, if you look in the console you will see getOptions fired, changing to foobar, value change: foo. Immediately after the changing to foobar message the value is changed back to foo. Most likely by the type ahead directive.